# VirtualBox Installation

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, installation, help

Sorry guys if this is a dumb question but I'm trying to learn all of this and am a bit confused.

I have Kali Linux installed as a 'Live" program to a USB stick. I'm looking at using the Oracle VirtualBox with the Kali Linux but was wondering how it should be installed. Should I install it on my Windows host system? can it be installed with Kali on the USB stick?

I'm hoping to not have to start all over and reinstall Kali and do things that way. Can the VM be installed over Kali on the USB stick?

Comment: It shouldn't and can't be installed in any live Linux. It can be installed in Windows. That said, this question is very confusing. First you need to be sure about what you want to do. And Kali is for professional pentesting, not a regular Linux distro. Kali is NOT for you.

Comment: Which Windows version? It would be better to install [Kali WSL](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/wsl-preparations/).

Comment: I have done both and in my own experience Kali works better in a true VM especially for penetration testing

Comment: Sure it's possible. Yes, also on a live system. But what's the goal? It'll be gone after a reboot.

Comment: @OP  - you should try my answer.  Kali 2024.1 is now out.  A VM is the only practical solution for pentesting and ongoing updates

Comment: There may be some "definition" issues here: "Live" in referring to OSes and especially Linux means an OS loaded primarily into memory from a USB (usually) that is booted to but never actually installed to permanent storage in the computer. It is helpful for testing or utility work, especially as it does not really impact the computer itself. To "install" an OS, by definition, means it is no longer "Live". You can run Live in a VM, or on a physical host, in pretty much the same way. Some Live distros installers are packaged as Live versions (Ubuntu), which confuses things, but doesn't actually.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the VM be installed over Kali on the USB stick?

No. Kali Live is not a VM.

If you wish a Kali VM (I am posting from Kali 2023.4 VM), then download the bare metal ISO from the Kali Site (I did that) and put it where you can see the ISO file from Virtual Box.

Now, Virtual Box, New Machine, set it up and point to the Kali ISO.

It will start to install, follow the prompts, and make your new VM. This works.

Do not be afraid to delete your first try and do it again. It is worth getting right because a Kali machine does rolling upgrades and can last a long time as a VM.

Virtual Box also supports USB pass through which you need for a USB wireless adapter for penetration testing.